# Google Analytics - Direct link to Google Analytics from my Google Account

Tags: google, google-analytics

I prefer to access my Google environment by going to `myaccount.google.com` first for multiple reasons.  It appears from this location I can access many of my Google applications, with the exception of my Google Analytics.  Why is that?  **How can I find an access link directly to my Google Analytics from my Google account**, rather that manually searching for the sign-in page on the web or relying on a bookmark associated to specific(s) browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we log into Google at `myaccount.google.com`, look towards the left sidebar and select **Data and Privacy** → **Apps and Services** → Click the **view more carrot** → **Other Google Services**.  You will then see the link to access Google Analytics.